# How does the OS language represented in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, localization

My Application is running in Linux.
it would be localized.
how can I get the OS Language?
is it represented in Linux?
as a numeric values?

Comment: Good question, but would need editing.

Comment: Would need relocation to SuperUser!

Comment: I mean- if i want to do switch(language) what are the values according to the os language, and how to retrieve them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most of your other questions relate to Qt, you might want to read the documentation of the static function [`QLocale::system()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlocale.html#system)

Answer (score 2):

See the question at SuperUser:

https://superuser.com/questions/62031/how-to-change-the-linux-localization

If you just want to know which locales are supported, you can see which are installed, which can be done in Debian by doing a:

```
ls -l /usr/share/locale
```

I guess the locale named "C" (the default locale name, which is just english) should always be installed.

And if you want to set the locale, just use:

```
export -n LC_ALL=de_DE
```

for German, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful information in the [GLibC Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Information.html#Locale-Information).